# PHP foreach loop doesnt itterate over objects, and won't start

Tags: php, html

Whenever i try the following loop

```
if (is_object($ueberweisung)) {

                            print_r($ueberweisung);
                            foreach ($ueberweisung as $item)
                            {
                                
                                echo '<h1>test</h1>';
                                echo '<tr>';

                                //echo '<td>' . $item['ibansender'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>' . $item->$u->getBetrag() . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>' . $item->u->getBicempfaenger() . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>' . $item->u->getBicempfaenger() . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>' . $item->u->getZahlungsreferenz() . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>' . $item->u->getVerwendungszweck() . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>' . $item->u->getBetrag() . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>' . $item->u->getDatum() . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                            }
                        }
```

it wont jump into that for each loop even though it is definitely a object and is not null$, and i don't know why.
$ueberweisung is filled by another class which is connected to a mysql database

```
public static function getUberweisungperIban($iban)
{
    $db = Database::connect();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ueberweisung WHERE ibansender = ?";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($iban));
    // fetch dataset (row) per ID, convert to Credentials-object (ORM)
    $ueberweisung = $stmt->fetchObject('Ueberweisung');
    //$ueberweisung = $stmt->fetchAll();
    //return $ueberweisung;
    Database::disconnect();
    //return $ueberweisung;
    return $ueberweisung !== false ? $ueberweisung : null;
}
```

Comment: What does that `print_r` show?

Comment: PHP will iterate over the **visible** properties of an object. Judging by the number of getters in your code it's possible that the object has no visible properties.